# why I don't have access to gitlab repository after doing git pull to update my local project?

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys, git-pull, git-remote

The team that I work for transferred the project from bitbucket to gitlab, so while I was working before the transfer, I didn't have any problem with bitbucket, I mean with the SSH key, I inserted on bitbucket the public key that I created with my laptop and everything's going well,  so I was doing git pull, push, add, commit...etc.
but after transferring the project to git-lab( I registered myself on git-lab and I was invited to the project by the boss, I put my public key on git-lab), I made `git remote set-URL origin git@gitlab.com:...path.../file.git` to update my origin project, so I didn't receive anything as a reply for this command line.
so after that, when I did `git pull`, I don't have access( permission denied ), I don't understand why.
you can see the picture bellow.
Is there someone here who knows why ?
THANKS [image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the origin url to the HTTPS url of the repository?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, how can I try that please ?

Comment: Git URLs come in two flavors. SSH: `git@gitlab.com:groupname/repository-name.git` and HTTPS: `https://gitlab.com/groupname/repository-name.git`. (In the case of a private repository the group name is your username.) They authenticate through different protocols so when one doesn't work I always try the other. However as John pointed out down below your origin is missing the group name and repository name.

Answer (score 1):

### Your Origin path is missing your repository

As @Daly pointed out, your origin url `git@gitlab.com` has no information about the repository. Your url should look something like this: `git@gitlab.com:username/project-name.git` You should log into gitlab and find the **clone** button, and click it. It will list your repository's origin URL for ssh (used in your example) and https.